# Is there any step for make properly zig-zag movement on unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

basically I want to make a Zig-zag movement on a 2d top-down and I have a problem when add`(input.getmousebuttondown(0))` it always blinked and not what i want

```
public float frequency = 10f;
public float magnitude = 5f;
public float speed = 10f;
float percentage = 0;

Vector3 pos;
Vector3 axis;

public Rigidbody2D rb2d;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    pos = transform.position;
    axis = transform.right;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Movement();
}

public void Movement()
{
    pos += Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed;
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
transform.position = pos + axis * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * frequency) * magnitude;
}
```

Also, I want the mechanics like that on on picture,
[image: I want the mechanics like this]

so when i tap the ball will zig-zag  but if i not tap the ball just go to right direction like on the pictures,

like this what i mean [image]

Comment: So you want the ball to automatically bounce off walls but also abruptly switch direction when tapped?

Comment: yes like that and also go to forward @verified_tinker

Comment: did you consider just doing it with physics? it would be dead easy

Comment: wheh you say **tap** do you mean "when I tap, it will change direction" or do you mean "during the time I am holding down it will zig zag".  game programming is difficult and subtle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you want the ball to zig-zag — abruptly change horizontal direction — when the player taps the screen.

**To do that, first you have to understand what velocity really is.** In this case, in this 2-dimensional world, velocity is composed of vertical and horizontal movement. In other words, you have a vector pulling at a horizontal direction (left or right) and you have one pulling at a vertical direction (up or down).

So, you can break down your ball's velocity into x and y components.

```
public float magnitude = 5f;
public float forwardSpeed = 10f;
public float horizontalSpeed = 10f;

private Vector2 horizontalAxis;

private void Start()
{
    horizontalAxis = Vector2.right;
}

private Vector2 GetCompositeVelocity()
{
    Vector2 forward = Vector2.up * forwardSpeed;
    Vector2 horizontal = horizontalAxis * horizontalSpeed;
    Vector2 composite = forward + horizontal;

    return Vector2.Clamp(composite, magnitude);
}
```

As you can see, `horizontalAxis` is set to the right direction at the start of the game. We need that to change based on user input. Here's how.

First, we introduce a negation vector, so that we can multiply the horizontal axis vector to get its opposite. I.e., when it's pointing right, multiplying it by the negator makes it point left. That's pretty simple to do.

```
private Vector2 negationVector;

private void Start()
{
    horizontalAxis = Vector2.right;
    negationVector = new Vector2(-1f, 0);
    // You can also write the above as negationVector = Vector2.Left. They're the same thing.
}

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    horizontalAxis *= negationVector;
    // E.g. (1, 0) * (-1, 0) = (-1, 0). Then, next time, (-1, 0) * (-1, 0) = (1, 0).
}
```

Finally, we have to update velocity when the user makes it change.

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    horizontalAxis *= negationVector;
    UpdateVelocity();
}

private void UpdateVelocity()
{
    Vector2 velocity = GetCompositeVelocity();
    rb2d.velocity = velocity;
}
```

Don't forget that we need to update the velocity at the start of the game. Additionally, I would move the code for initializing `horizontalAxis` and `negationVector` to `Awake()`, which is called before `Start()`. You don't *have* to do this, but it's good practice.

```
private void Awake()
{
    horizontalAxis = Vector2.right;
    negationVector = new Vector2(-1f, 0);
}

private void Start()
{
    UpdateVelocity();
}
```

It's also a good idea to extract the logic that changes directions into a separate method, in case you want to do that from a method other than `OnMouseDown()`.

**As a whole, we get this:**

```
public float magnitude = 5f;
public float forwardSpeed = 10f;
public float horizontalSpeed = 10f;

private Vector2 horizontalAxis;
private Vector2 negationVector;

public Rigidbody2D rb2d;

private void Awake()
{
    horizontalAxis = Vector2.right;
    negationVector = new Vector2(-1f, 0);
}

private void Start()
{
    UpdateVelocity();
}

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    ReverseHorizontalVector();
    UpdateVelocity();
}

private void ReverseHorizontalVector()
{
    horizontalAxis *= negationVector;
}

private void UpdateVelocity()
{
    Vector2 velocity = GetCompositeVelocity();
    rb2d.velocity = velocity;
}

private Vector2 GetCompositeVelocity()
{
    Vector2 forward = Vector2.up * forwardSpeed;
    Vector2 horizontal = horizontalAxis * horizontalSpeed;
    Vector2 composite = (forward + horizontal);

    return Vector2.Clamp(composite, magnitude);
}
```

If you want something to happen when the ball collides with something (such as a wall), you can do that inside [`OnCollisionEnter2D()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) or [`OnTriggerEnter2D()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html). The implementation of that is outside the scope of this question, but you can see examples in the links provided (which point to the official documentation).

Answer (score 1):

Your `Movement()` function runs for once because you're basically saying, "run this function when i click" and if you want that function to run every frame (I'm assuming that because you put it in `Update()`), you have to click every frame which is impossible.

Try to only change the destination of your object when user clicks and move the object in another function without any `if` conditions.

Like this:

```
Update(){
       Movement();
       ChangeDirection();
    }
    
    void Movement(){
      //move object every frame without any conditions. Don't use GetMouseButtonDown() here****
    }
    
    void ChangeDirection(){
      if(GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
//Change the direction of object. For example, if it currently goes to the 
//left, set the direction to the right. Because your Movement() works every
//frame, just changing the direction to the opposite is will be enough.
        }
    }
```

You can check [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/c-creating-zigzag-movement.326938/) out if you want to create an zigzag effect.

Comment: I don't understand this mean`Try to only change the destination of your object when user clicks and move the object in another function without any if conditions.`, 
can you explain it more with script

Comment: The problem is my script in this 
```pos += Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed;
transform.position = pos + axis * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * frequency) * magnitude;```

its already on ping pong so it will zig-zag at the first run and I don't wanna do that

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you want logic something like this:

You need a state variable for "direction" which is probably either "left" or "right".  It looks like you also want "straight".

Your logic would look like this:

```
begin run:
direction = straight
ready player one

screen tapped:
if direction == straight, direction = right
if direction == right, direction = left
if direction == left, direction = right
// (or whatever logic you prefer)

each frame:
1. move the ball appropriately for "direction"
2. collision with walls/etc?
     if direction == right, direction = left
     if direction == left, direction = right
2. collision with keepers?
     run is over
```

I'm pretty sure that's the logic you're looking for.

Again the secret is you need a **state** for direction, toggle the parity of it (or whatever is correct in the game).